# Is there cudnnLSTM or cudNNGRU alternative in tensorflow 2.0

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, recurrent-neural-network, tensorflow2.0

The `CuDNNGRU` in `TensorFlow 1.0` is really fast. But when I shifted to `TensorFlow 2.0` i am unable to find `CuDNNGRU`. Simple `GRU` is really slow in  `TensorFlow 2.0`.

Is there any way to use `CuDNNGRU` in `TensorFlow 2.0`?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The importable implementations have been deprecated - instead, `LSTM` and `GRU` will default to `CuDNNLSTM` and `CuDNNGRU` if all [conditions are met](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r2.1/tensorflow/python/keras/layers/recurrent_v2.py#L902):

1. `activation = 'tanh'`
2. `recurrent_activation = 'sigmoid'`
3. `recurrent_dropout = 0`
4. `unroll = False`
5. `use_bias = True`
6. Inputs, *if masked*, are strictly right-padded
7. `reset_after = True` (GRU only)

---

Also ensure TensorFlow uses GPU:

```py
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.python.client import device_lib
print(device_lib.list_local_devices())
print('Default GPU Device: {}'.format(tf.test.gpu_device_name()))
```

---

**Update**: there appears to be a problem w/ TF 2.0.0 when running on Colab in getting CuDNN to work; try `!pip install tensorflow==2.1.0` instead.

Comment: i tried this
` x, x_h, x_c = Bidirectional(GRU(50, activation= 'tanh',recurrent_activation ='sigmoid',recurrent_dropout=0,
                      unroll =False,use_bias =True,reset_after=True,return_sequences = True, return_state = True))(x)` but it take the same time as without these parameters. this is `10` time more than `CuDNNGRU`

Comment: @TalhaAnwar Does your TensorFlow use GPU? See updated answer; also, are your inputs padded or masked?

Comment: yes, i  am using colab gpu and my inputs are post padded to make all sentence of equal length, which i think is right-padded

Comment: @TalhaAnwar Nevermind my earlier suggestion, the docstring is falsely phrased; the inputs, if padded, _should_ be strictly right-padded (i.e. never left). Is this the case, and do you use masking?

Comment: i even tried `pre` paddings but it took around the same time, with `post` paddings. No, i am not doing masking.

Comment: i am simply trying to train GRU with glove embeddings. Previously i am with TF 1.0 and CuDNN saves a lot of time. I just switched to TF 2.0 and its too slow

Comment: @TalhaAnwar Strange, I was able to reproduce your problem without any padding - but it was resolved after upgrading to 2.1; try `!pip install tensorflow==2.1.0`.

Comment: Thanks this truly worked for me by setting the told perimeters.