# why do i get a tensorflow.contrib error with tensorflow 2.0?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am trying to figure out why do i keep getting this error

```
from tensorflow.contrib.cudnn_rnn.python.ops import cudnn_rnn_ops
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow.contrib'
```

I am using tensorflow 2.0 with python 3.7.6 debugging this code snippet with visual studio code every thing works fine add the cuda toolkit and it detects it  but when i get to the second line in the code below i get an error about `tensorflow.contrib` after some search i found that tensorflow 2.0 does not have contrib module this was for the older tensorflow versions , if I change `CuDNNLSTM` to `LSTM` the error is gone and program trains fine but painfully slow , so is there a work around for this error

below is the model i am using for training

```
    regressor = Sequential()
    
    regressor.add(CuDNNLSTM(units = 100, return_sequences = True, input_shape = (X_train.shape[1], 1)))
    regressor.add(Dropout(0.2))



    regressor.add(CuDNNLSTM(units = 100, activation='relu',return_sequences = True))
    regressor.add(Dropout(0.2))

    regressor.add(CuDNNLSTM(units = 100, activation='relu',return_sequences = True))
    regressor.add(Dropout(0.2))

 

    regressor.add(Dense(units = 100))
    regressor.add(Dropout(0.2))

    regressor.add(Dense(units = 100))
    regressor.add(Dropout(0.2))
                                                                     
    regressor.compile(optimizer = 'adam', loss = 'mean_squared_error' ,metrics=['accuracy'])

    regressor.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs = 300, batch_size =100)
```

Comment: Check out [Is there cudnnLSTM or cudNNGRU alternative in tensorflow 2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60468385/is-there-cudnnlstm-or-cudnngru-alternative-in-tensorflow-2-0)

Comment: I tried using LSTM but it does not use my gpu and my gpu load is below 5% when the model is training

Comment: If you read one of the answers, it says that a few requirements must be met. One of them includes the activation function. You use relu, but tanh must be used for GPU.

Comment: Tensorflow.contrib is removed from Tf 2.x. use `tf.compat.v1.keras.layers.CuDNNLSTM` instead with GPU card. Essentially it uses GPU acceleration. Make sure you have set tf GPU configuration True. Thanks!